# Using and building 3rd party controls via Xamarin and C#

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Xamarin seems to be a pretty good platform for developing cross platform applications, although some very obvious questions pop in mind, for which I couldn't get a decent answer using my limited google-foo skills. I was wondering if the experts here might give me a sound advice on the following:

1. I would like to keep the freedom of choosing between raw development and 3rd party components when developing my application. Is this something I can do using Xamarin? (Assuming that 3rd party controls are typically intended to be used in the native development ecosystem.)
2. Is it possible to develop controls using Xamarin which can be used/consumed by other native OS app developers?
3. Has Xamarin been quick or sloppy in terms of adapting to changes to the native platforms? Basically how much would be a typical lead time before the new features in a fresh iOS or Android release gets trickled down to Xamarin. (Which is where my lead time to use and publish my updates starts.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can certainly use 3rd party components, Xamarin has a [new component store](http://components.xamarin.com/) for distributing those in Xamarin Studio, you will also be able to use NuGet in Visual Studio with the new version coming out. You can also bind native libraries, if you happen to find an objective-C or java library you want to use.
2. You can certainly do this for other Xamarin developers through the component store. Distributing C# controls to native developers is probably not easy, however, as they would have to load up the Mono runtime to use your control.
3. They have been very fast, in fact, they launched [MonoTouch 6.0](http://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-releases-same-day-support-for-ios-6/) the same day Apple released iOS 6.